# Fields are rendering white space at either side

Tags: nodes, entities

I am rendering my node fields using:

```
<?php print render($content['field_website_link']); ?>
```

On the front end this is printing as:

```
<a class="upper" href="            http://www.domain.co.uk    " 
title="Link to our Website" target="_blank">Visit Website →</a>
```

For some reason it is adding the same whitespace around the rendered field. The field format is plain text and their is no whitespace in the actual field. This is the same for all text fields.

Any ideas?

Thanks Robert

Comment: I would suggest there might be something haywire in your theme or a field preprocess. Dont paste the results here but what do those field values look like if you do `<pre><?php print_r($content);?></pre>`?

Comment: The fields look fine when I do a print_r on them. They look how they should. There is no CSS on them either that would be adding it. For now I have used PHP trim but shouldn't need to use this.

Comment: Something which tests if it is the theme messing with output is to switch to one of the default themes and then view those fields/pages.